# How can I make foremost work?

Tags: data-recovery

I'm trying to use `foremost` to recover a lost .ods file created with LibreOffice Calc on an Ubuntu 18.04 system.

The command I'm running is

```
$ sudo foremost -i /dev/nvme0n1 -t ole -o /media/user/external-drive/recovery/
```

When this command finishes, the `/media/user/external-drive/recovery/` file contains nothing but a file `audit.txt` that says "0 FILES EXTRACTED".

Even if the .ods file I'm looking for is lost, I'm 100% certain that there are other .ods files on the drive that it should have found.  So, something must be wrong.  Since the `audit.txt` file writes correctly, I must have the `-o` target specified correctly, and there are only two other things I could be doing wrong:

1. `-t ole` isn't the correct option for .ods files.  `man foremost` gives a list of files that doesn't include .ods, but there is `ole` for "PowerPoint, Word, Excel, Access, and StarWriter," so it's the closest thing on the list as far as I could tell.  Is this correct?  Should the `ole` option pick up .ods files?
2. `/dev/nvme0n1` isn't correct as my hard drive.  I can't find any information on how to unambigiously determine what your hard drive is, but `lshw` gives

```
    $ sudo lshw -short -C disk
    H/W path           Device          Class          Description
    =============================================================
    /0/100/1d/0/0/1    /dev/nvme0n1    disk           256GB NVMe namespace
    /0/0/0.0.0         /dev/sda        disk           500GB External Drive
```

and nothing else, so by process of elimination I have to assume the `nvme0n1` option is the hard drive where I expect .ods files to be found.  Is this wrong?  Is there another thing I can do to determine if this is the right drive?

Why does `foremost` not detect .ods files that I know are present?

**Edit** 2) is the problem.  The secret command for finding your hard drive is `df`, not `lshw` or `lsblk` like I was trying.  This correctly identified my root partition as `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root`

Re-running the `foremost` command with the correct drive,

```
$ sudo foremost -i /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root -t ole -o /media/user/external-drive/recovery/
```

Returns 20+ files of the form `{9-digit number}.ole`.  None of the guides I've read say what I'm supposed to do with these; the names mean nothing, the contents aren't human-readable, and I don't have any programs to open whatever an .ole file is.

I tried opening them in LibreOffice Calc.  One was a LibreOffice Writer file I recognized, the rest opened as gibberish even in Calc.

Again, even if the file I'm looking for is gone, `foremost` should have found other .ods files that I know for a fact are present on the hard drive.  All files are on the same root partition.

So, how do I make sense of what `foremost` returns, and how do I fix it to return files that it should be finding?

Comment: Why dont you try photorec?

Comment: `photorec` is far more difficult to use.  It has to be run through a LiveUSB session, it also doesn't have a clear option for .ods files, and it wouldn't allow me to advance past the screen where I choose a filetype.  It doesn't matter why I didn't use `photorec`, though.  The question I've asked is well-defined and should have a documentable answer regardeless of the existence of any alternatives.

Comment: Tosh.   Photorec does not require a live USB session, and technically will work on a live partition - although doing this does break several rules of data recovery.  Photorec absolutely supports recovery of ods files (https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/File_Formats_Recovered_By_PhotoRec).  I note ODS files are in fact zipped XML files, but photorec handles them just fine.   I just did a test.

Comment: Also, I just had a play with foremost - in addition to being harder to use (but useful in that it can  target certain file types) , it recovered the ods files, but it recovered them as zip files, unlike photorec that recovered the same files and recognized the ods extension.

Comment: Your NVMe0n1 disk is likely the correct place to find the files if they are on your internal drive, although its quite possible that the actual files are in a partition - which this does not show.  You may want to update your question with where you saved the data and the output of "df"

Comment: To recover the ods files in Firemost I used "-t ods"

Comment: `-t ods` doesn't work, using it returns "usage" info to indicate I've given a bad option.  However, `df` is useful for identifying my root partition, which was wrong.  Running the command with the correct disk name, `foremost` finds several .ole files.  I don't know what I'm supposed to do with these, but I tried opening some in LibreOffice Calc.  None of them were any of the .ods files I expected to find.  One was a text file that I recognized.  I only have one partition, so they should all be there.  `foremost` still isn't finding what it should.